# Set Multiple Background of One HTML Element

Tags: html, css

I want to set different `background`s of a `div`.

1) A color that will be on whole background.

2) An image on the right.

3) Another image on left.

Something like this

HTML

```
<div class="theTwoBG" />
```

CSS

```
.theTwoBG {
   background: #24a342, url('path/to/image1.png') no-repeat right, url('path/to/image2.png') no-repeat left;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: use background-color & background-image

Comment: u can go for :after :before css  to set left and right background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)  you need to add background-position

```
.multi_bg_example {
  background: url(http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/resources/images/logos/firefox-48.png),
        linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),  rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)),
        url(http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/resources/images/patterns/flowers-pattern.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: bottom right, left, right;
}
```

**Important:**

In your case you are using the **shorthand writing**, here is a working demo for that

```css
.multi_bg_example {
width: 480px;
height: 300px;
background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/) no-repeat left top,url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class=multi_bg_example></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be usefull...

```
<div class="my_cls">
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .my_cls {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        background: url("3.jpg") center left, url("4.jpg") center right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        background-position: left, right;
        background-size: 200px, 100px;
    }
</style>
```